# How do I copy a file from a usb to a folder in CentOS 7

Tags: centos

Looked for weeks no one seems to know or you just get "use cp" and the manuals are too vague or don't seem to work properly. Have used mount drive without errors.

Comment: As long as you don't give any details why this isn't working for you, it's the best answer you can get, along with "use a file manager". [ask]

Comment: There are no errors coming up but file is not in destination and find is not getting a result. Use a file manager would be great. Also so would details

Comment: What details are needed here How to ask is also very vague

Comment: You need to explain what you’ve tried, in detail (as in, give actual commands you’ve run, or explain actions you’ve taken in a GUI), what you expected to happen, and what happened instead (or didn’t happen).

Comment: Finally got the piece that you all must take for granted.. This needs merging with "How can I copy a file from a usb drive to a directory on the hard drive in Centos 6?" and the piece in between needs to be clarified.

Comment: I found the answer by accident there is a step missing from all the answers I've tried. So keep voting me down people and as you do think about how once you were new and struggling with an answer when there was nothing and no one good enough to help.

Comment: Here is the system that did NOT work. For those that may need a hint. 1. mkdir /media/USB 2.chmod +x /media/USB 3.mount -t /dev/sdc1 /media/USB 4. cp –r Mod.tar /home/server/Mod. 5. sync 6. umount /media/USB This finishes with immediate return of cursor with no errors showing.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to run the `cp` command indicating where you want to copy from and where you want to copy to.

Example: `cp /placewhereyoumounttheusb/myfile.log /placewhereyouwantoittobe/`

Comment: Thank you. Your are the only one here that cared enough to even attempt to assist.